# Vuex: Fetch data with axios based on already fetched data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm fetching data from an external API via axios in the Vuex store, which gives me an array with objects - let's say - `cities`.

Each `city` has a `zipCode`, which I need to fetch city details with.
I want to add that details-object as a new key to the `cities` array.

Right now I'm fetching all cities and have another Vuex action to fetch the city details.

> ACTION to fetch all cities

```
fetchCities: ({ commit, state, dispatch }) => {
  let baseUrl = "https://my-url/cities";

  let config = {
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: ...
    },
    params: {
      param1: "a",
      param2: "b"
    }
  };

  axios
    .get(baseUrl, config)
    .then(function(response) {
      commit("UPDATE_CITIES_RAW", response.data.items);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  dispatch("fetchCityDetails");
},
```

> MUTATION after fetching all cities

```
UPDATE_CITIES_RAW: (state, payload) => {
  state.citiesRaw = payload;
},
```

Each object in that array has a `zipCode`, which I'm fetching details about this city with.

I tried to loop the `citiesRaw` array inside the action to fetch the details and commit a change for each iteration, **but the array from the state is empty at this point**, because the action gets called before the mutation.

> ACTION to fetch city details

```
fetchCityDetails: ({ commit, state }) => {
  let baseUrl = "https://my-url/cities/"

  let config = {
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: ...
    }
  };

  // citiesRaw is empty at this point
  state.citiesRaw.forEach(e => {
    let url = baseUrl + e.zipCode;

    axios
      .get(url, config)
      .then(function(response) {
        commit("UPDATE_CITY_DETAILS", {
          response: response.data,
          zipCode: e.zipCode
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
},
```

What are the best ways to wait for the first fetch and then update the array?

Should I even use the same array or create a new one to begin with?

Or is there even a better way to fetch based on fetched data in the Vuex store?

> UPDATE

After fixing the dispatching before the async function even finished (thanks, @Y-Gherbi), I also refactored the way of fetching the details:

1. Component dispatches  `fetchCities`
2. in `fetchCities` action: commit  `UPDATE_CITIES`
3. in `UPDATE_CITIES` mutation: .map on the payload and create new object -> push all to `state.cities`
4. in `fetchCities` action: loop `state.cities` & dispatch  `fetchCityDetails(zipCode)` for each city
5. in `fetchCityDetails` action: commit  `UPDATE_CITY_DETAILS`
6. in `UPDATE_CITY_DETAILS` mutation: .map on `state.cities`  and add  `cityDetails` object  to the referred city object

> new actions

```
fetchCities: ({ commit, state, dispatch }) => {
  let baseUrl = "https://my-url/cities";

  let config = {
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: ...
    },
    params: {
      param1: "a",
      param2: "b"
    }
  };

  let url = baseUrl;

  axios
    .get(url, config)
    .then(function(response) {
        commit("UPDATE_CITIES", response.data.items);
        state.cities.forEach(city => {
          dispatch("fetchCityDetails", city.zipCode);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
fetchCityDetails: ({ commit }, zipCode) => {
  let baseUrl = "https://my-url/cities";

  let config = {
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: ...
    },
  };

  let url = baseUrl + "/" + zipCode;

  axios
    .get(url, config)
    .then(function(response) {
      commit("UPDATE_CITY_DETAILS", {
        cityDetails: response.data,
        zipCode: zipCode
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

> new mutations

```
UPDATE_CITIES: (state, cities) => {
  // I don't need all data & I want to rename the keys from the response,
  // so I create a new object
  cities = cities.map(city => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.zipCode = city.zip_code
    obj.key1 = city.key_1;
    obj.key2 = city.key_2;

    return obj;
  });
  state.cities.push(...cities);
},
UPDATE_CITY_DETAILS: (state, payload) => {
  let cities = state.cities;
  // add one details-object for each city
  cities = cities.map(city => {
    if (city.zipCode == payload.zipCode) {
      city.cityDetails = payload.cityDetails;
    }
    return city;
  });
  state.cities = cities;
}
```

The question remains: Is there a better/more optimized approach to this kind of fetching?

Comment: could you show the whole vuex store code?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim What more do you need? There's only the one mutation, which is not even executed, is missing.

Comment: i'm loosing the wire when trying to bind your code snippets,may be because i'm tired

Comment: Try moving the dispatch function on the next line after the commit function. The array (citiesRaw) is empty because you are calling the action before the data is fetchen (because axios.get is async)

Comment: I got a few questions while thinking about a better way of dealing with this. 1. Do you need all the citydetails at the same time of just one (or a few) on each detailpage or something like that? 2. How many cities is the backend providing? And is there a way to limit that based on something like a userId?

Comment: @Y.Gherbi 1. I display the cities-array in a table. The table has expandable rows (on click), which show the details per city 2. the fetching of the cities is based on a search result, it's around 100-1000 cities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there are much better and elegant ways to deal with this but to simply help you with the bug (looping over an empty array that's expected to be an array of cities)

**fix**

Try moving the dispatch function to the next line after the commit function. The `array` (`citiesRaw`) is empty because you are calling the action before the data is fetched (because `axios.get` is an async operation)

---

**alternative solution**

As you said, the cities are displayed in a table with expandable rows, which are used to display the city details. Fetching 100-1000 cities is quite a lot of data but it's still one call to the back-end. But looping over all these items and doing a request for every one of them could be problematic from a performance and bandwidth (if that's the correct term for large data usage) perspective.

Personally, I would handle each request whenever the user actually needs this data. In your case whenever the user clicked on a row to expand it.

**Storing it in the store?**

Whenever you want to store the city details in the store is up to you. You could just keep it in the component but personally, I would use it as some kind of cache mechanism.

When the user clicked on a row, check if the details are already fetched

```
if(!state.cityDetails[key]) {
    axios.get()
        .then(res => {
            // Commit a mutation that saves the fetched details
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle error
        })
} else {
    // Use the 'cached' cityDetails
}
```

Your store could look something like this:

```
{
    cityDetails: {
        keyCouldBeIdOrZipcode: {...},
        anOtherAlreadyFetchedCity: {...},
    }
}
```

*sorry for the typos and bad formatting. Typing code on a phone is horrible*

Comment: In the meantime I'm thinking of a more elegant way to handle this, pretty interesting case!

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the undefined array. Still: I would really like to know if there is a better way to do something like this.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution. You could make it as comprehensive as you want but I hope that this is a good start

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, there is one catch though: I display most of the details in the expanded row, but some data from the details is actually displayed at the row (that gets clicked), so I desperately need to fetch all details for all cities, regardless of whether the row got clicked or not.

Comment: If providing these values from the back-end with the first request isn't possible, you probably need to go with your first approach...